# Where condition with array in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want to query many-to-many models. My models look like this,

```
class Role {
    String name
    static hasMany = [users: User]
}
class User {
    String name
    String email
    static hasMany = [roles : role]
    static belongsTo = Role
}
```

And Here are my tables in database,

```
role              role_users                  user 
---------------   -------------------------  ---------------------------------
|id  |name    |   |role_id  |user_id      |  |id |name     |email            |
---------------   -------------------------  ---------------------------------
|1   |Owner   |   |1        |1            |  |1  |Harry    |harry@mail.com   |
|2   |Designer|   |2        |2            |  |2  |Hermione |hermione@mail.com|
|3   |Cleaner |   |3        |3            |  |3  |Ron      |ron@mail.com     |
---------------   -------------------------  ---------------------------------
```

Here is my query code to query,

```
def myId = [1,2,3]
def users = User.executeQuery("select u from User as u join u.roles r where r.id = :id ", [id : myId])
```

How do I query with condition in array?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't 100% clear what your criteria need to be but if I understand your example then I think something like this would work:

```
def myIds = [2l, 3l]
def users = User.executeQuery("select u from User as u join u.roles as r where r.id in (:ids) ", [ids : myIds])
```

If you didn't really want to use HQL you could do something like this:

```
def myIds = [2l, 3l]
def users = User.where {
    roles {
        id in myIds
    }
}.list()
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `in` instead of `=` to check against a list.  Be sure, that the list you are checking against contains items (an empty list will give you an SQL error):

```
def users = User.executeQuery("select u from User as u join u.roles r where r.id in :ids ", [ids: myIds])
```